# Xsl escape Sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

See the output below the name contains the apostrophe which breaks the code, how can i use urlencode or something else to fix the issue

**Output

'&titel=A&Name=S'Tariq&number=1&ud=1&op=3'**

```
<xsl:text>&amp;titel=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="osttitle"/>
                <xsl:text>&amp;Name=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ostName"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="NameJS"/>
                <xsl:text>&amp;number=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ostnumber"/>
                <xsl:text>&amp;ud=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ostudnumber"/>
                <xsl:text>&amp;op=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="osnumber"/>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move to XSLT 2.0, the function `encode-for-uri()` is available.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-encode-for-uri

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103205/xslt-replace-apostrophe-with-escaped-text-in-output     see this url, the question is exactly the same but when i call the template it gives me error " xsl text cannot be the child node of call template "