# Replacing string in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt1.0. My input is

```
<xsl:variable name="string">width:12pt;border-width:13pt</xsl:variable>
```

I want to replace the -width: into some other string, but not the width:(width starting with - alone should replaced).How to do it in xslt 1.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT Replace function not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069092/xslt-replace-function-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no replace function in XSLT 1.0. You can find [here (String.Replace() in XSLT)](http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) a template that can do that.

You can use it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="string">
  <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="width:12pt;border-width:13pt" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="-width" />
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="other-string" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```